# scp : keep transaction logs?

Tags: logs, scp

Suppose you `scp` a file to remote server.

```
scp /file root@<ip>:/file
```

on the remote server SCP sees a file named `/file`

that is to be categorized as "incoming"

can this info be echo-ed to a file

```
 echo "incoming:/file" >> /scp_logs
```

?

**UPDATE:**

or perhaps.. can `scp` be configured to run a command as well after transferring a file to the remote server ( before it disconnects from the server)?

this way I can attach the

```
 echo "incoming:/file" >> /scp_logs
```

to it while transferring the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No and yes. The `scp` issues normal `ssh` sessions with some remote command (also `scp`), but it is hardcoded in the binaries. So there is possibility to modify the client side binary to send also your `echo` command.

Or force this policy on the server using `ForceCommand` script, which would inspect `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable and in case of `scp`, it would store the arguments in the log.

But that would not solve the case when you do scp command such as `scp file1 file2 server:/path/`, because server will see only the remote path. To get also the real path what files are actually uploaded, you would need to modify `scp` binary on the server to do the logging for you (somewhere around the [`open()`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c#L1105) call).

So if you are looking for some way of auditable file uploads, `scp` is not a way to go. You would be much better with `sftp`, which logs all the commands out of the box (once you enable `LogLevel VERBOSE`).